# Does this bubble sort work?

Tags: bubble-sort

1. Data to sort:

   - 410
   - 253
   - 330
   - 124
   - 285
2. Result after running the function below:

   - 410
   - 330
   - 253
   - 285
   - 124

   > function SortData()
   >
   > > i as integer
   > >
   > > > i= numDat.length
   > > >
   > > > > j as integer= 0
   > > > >
   > > > > > temp as integer

   ```
   //Bubble Sort
   while(i> 0)
       while(j< i- 1)
           if(numDat[j] < numDat[j+ 1])
               temp= numDat[j+ 1]
               numDat[j+ 1]= numDat[j]
               numDat[j]= temp
           endif
           j= j+ 1
       endwhile
       i= i- 1
   endwhile
   ```

   > endfunction

I have been scratching my head for a good time now, if someone could help it would be much appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: `j` must be initialized before each (inner) loop otherwise the inner loop will only run once.

Comment: thank both of you @K3N that was the problem and I feel stupid thank you!

Comment: No problem, easy to miss

Comment: @PaulBirkholtz it okay most of us does that.

Answer (score 1):

In bubble sort after each iteration, we need to initialize next iteration to initial values.

```
 while(i> 0)
        j = 0
        while(j< i- 1)
            if(numDat[j] < numDat[j+ 1])
                temp= numDat[j+ 1]
                numDat[j+ 1]= numDat[j]
                numDat[j]= temp
            endif
            j= j+ 1
        endwhile
        i= i- 1
    endwhile
```